# UDP Receiver trigger a function after some delay?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, udp

I am coding some simple local machine search program. What i do is sending a UDP broadcast message and then wait for returning messages from the machines.

Sender side:

```
setInterval(function sendUDP() { 

var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

client.bind(function() { client.setBroadcast(false) });

var message = new Buffer('getinfo');

client.send(message, 0, message.length, 9080, "192.168.43.255", function(err, bytes) {
     client.close();
 });

console.log("sended");

return sendUDP; }(), 10000);
```

Sender side sends a UDP packet as a broadcast message, and the machines that receives those messages replies back via another port. I am listening these incoming messages on server side like:

```
var functions = require('./functiones.js');

var PORT = 9081;
var HOST = '0.0.0.0';


var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

var IPAddresses=new Array();

server.on('listening', function () {
   var address = server.address();      
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + 
address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
   IPAddresses.push(remote.address);
   console.log(String(message));
  console.log(functions.parseToName(message));
});
server.bind(PORT, HOST); 
//updateJSON(IPAddresses);
```

So with above code i can take all messages.

What i want to do is that creating a json file after taking all messages. Let's say i have 20 machines on the network and i need to trigger another function by passing `IPAddressess` array into it.  But machines just send messages, i may take 15 messages out of 20, the count is not important, if i do not have 5 machines on the network, then i will say their status is off. To create and Update a json file i need to trigger another function after receiver take messages from machines, but i cannot handle in which way i must trigger that function. There is no message coming by saying "yes my operation is done you can trigger that function to update JSON file".
If i have a counter that always triggers that functions when time is out, i would probably have a conflict with sender side's timeout.

Any advice and help would be great.

Sincerely